# printThis.js sometime do not print content

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, printthis

I am using printThis.js and trying to print html using angularjs. My code is

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.Html = '<div><p>Pakistan</p></div>';
    $scope.printMe = function (){
        $dvPrint = $($scope.Html);

                $dvPrint.printThis();
    }
}
```

Html Code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button id="print_btn" ng-click="printMe()">click it</button><br />
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/22511/)

What issue i am facing is, if i am working on local machine, it works perfect. but if i deploy it on local server then sometime print preview is empty. whereas when debugging deployed code on server printthis.js works.

i tried to increase timeout time in printthis.js but it didn't worked. any thoughts on this issue? My jquery version is 2.1.0

One more thing i would like to add here is, if i edit the html content which i need to print after page is load, then printThis.js will work fine and content will be in print preview. in other case if page rendered and html content is loaded at the first time printThis.js will render empty preview.

Comment: My guess is that it's a timing issue. When printThis is executed, the HTML may not be 'attached' to the DOM because it is being added dynamically immediately before printThis. Try adding a timeout before calling printThis and if that works then it is a timing issue.

Comment: You mean to add timeout in my function which is invoking print this.js??

Comment: yes, that way you can confirm if it is a timing issue.

Answer (score 1):

can you try in CSS side... This is the code

```
@media print {
```

.show{font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;display:block;}
}

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried but this also didn't worked. Print Preview is still empty. but if i will edit text of html i.e. if i change Pakistan to PAK and print then it will work. I guess there is some instance in printThis.js which is not being initialize or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Worked in my localMachine

```
 $scope.Html = '<div><p>Pakistan</p></div>';
        $scope.printMe = function () {
            $scope.dvPrint = $($scope.Html);
            $scope.dvPrint.printThis();
        };
```

Comment: on my local machine it also works, but if you deploy on difference machine and access from your machine on same network it will render empty preview

Comment: can you try with my changes ??

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just tested it by adding your changes on server. Result is same as previous. print preview is empty whereas working if i debug

Comment: but if i edit the text of html i.e. change paksitan to pak then it work. whereas it suppose to work with same content which is loaded at first time when page was rendered